# Поочерёдное открытие окон в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Например, есть `QMainWindow`, где находится форма входа (логин, пароль). При нажатии открывается еще один `QMainWindow`, уже сама программа, а старое окно закрывается при вводе данных.

Правильно ли такое соотношение? В этом случае, мне не нравится то, что когда окно закрывается, второе окно отображается в другом месте, и размеры окна тоже меняются (или же уходит с полноэкранного режима).

Или лучше сделать так: одно окно `QMainWindow`, на котором будет панель с логином; при вводе верных данных скрыть его и открыть другую панель, где сама суть проги.

Посоветуйте, как правильно поступить. В Qt я новичок.

Comment: То что вы описали называется бизнесс логикой приложения, и в большинстве случаев она описывается в тех задании, если этого нет, то на личное усмотрение.

Comment: на Ваше усмотрение, какой способ будет лучше? И будет ли верным использовать 2 объекта QMainWindow? И если так, то есть ли встроенные возможности для появления второго окна в том же месте, где было первое, с теми же размерами?

Comment: Все оказалось действительно просто, нашел решение: this->setGeometry(parent->geometry());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд, тащить QMainWindow ради формы с логином и паролем это чересчур.

Первый вариант: если вам при загрузке программы уже надо иметь QMainWindow на весь экран, то проще отнаследоваться от QWidget, реализовать поля ввода и их логику. Разместить его в QMainWindow.

Второй вариант: если QMainWindow пока не нужен, а нужна просто форма с полями ввода, то отнаследуйтесь от QDialog. Запускайте его.

При готовности, передавайте введённые данные дальше в обработчик. Если данные корректны, то (первый вариант) удаляете QWidget и размещаете новый centralWidget на QMainWindow со всем вашим интерфейсом или (второй вариант) закрываете QDialog и создаёте QMainWindow.

В любом случае, если основное окно долго создавать, то его можно сделать сразу при загрузке программы, а после ввода данные просто вставлять в layout.

Если вообще ничего неохота удалять, закрывать и тд, то QStackedWidget без возможности пользовательского переключения. На одной вкладке будет ваша форма, на другой всё остальное. Меняете программно.

Comment: Премного благодарен за развернутый ответ, Вы мне очень помогли! Выбрал вариант с заменой и удалением виджета.

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось действительно просто, решил оставить 1 вариант и использовать следующее:
`this->setGeometry(parent->geometry());`